# Count the frequency of a specific word on a specific URL - Python

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, word-count

I am hoping to get a count of how often a specific word shows on a given URL. I currently have a way to do this for a small set of URLs and a single word:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = ["https://www.example.org/","https://www.example.com/"]

#the_word = input()
the_word = 'Python'

total_words = []
for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
    words = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and the_word.lower() in text)
    count = len(words)
    words_list = [ ele.strip() for ele in words ]
    for word in words:
        total_words.append(word.strip())

    print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} of word: {}'.format(url, count, the_word))
    print(words_list)


#print(total_words)
total_count = len(total_words)
```

However, my hope is to be able to do this for a mapped set of words to their respective URLs as shown in the below data frame.

| Target Word | Target URL |
| --- | --- |
| word1 | [www.example.com/topic-1/](http://www.example.com/topic-1/) |
| word2 | [www.example.com/topic-2/](http://www.example.com/topic-2/) |

The output would ideally give me a new column with a count of how often the word shows on its associated URL. For example, how often *'word1'* shows on *'www.example.com/topic-1/'*.

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `str.count()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over your structure - dict, list of dicts, ... Following example will just point in a direction, cause your question is not that clear and is missing an exact expected result. I am sure you could adapt it to your special needs.

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'word':'Python','url':'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python'},
    {'word':'Question','url':'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python'}
]

for item in data:
    r = requests.get(item['url'], allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
    count = soup.body.get_text(strip=True).lower().count(item['word'].lower())
    item['count'] = count

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

| word | url | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Python | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python | 93 |
| Question | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python | 13 |

**NOTE:** *Depending on what you want to determine the word frequency, you should consider the following:*

1. human readable is to be extracted separately from the html e.g. with BeautifulSoup.
2. depending on how the content of the web page is provided static / dynamic the tool has to be chosen. For dynamic content, for example, [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/overview/components/) is to be preferred, because unlike requests it also renders JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! this is helpful. The output you've shown is exactly what I am looking for. I am using a csv that I have turned into a list of dictionaries similar to what you have above. However I am having trouble looping over the list of dicts to get the same output. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks again! Updated question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581444/word-frequency-by-iterating-over-a-list-of-dictionaries-python

Comment: @AlexFuss Saw you found your answer, great - Also added a note with some context, to my answer, in case you are dealing with dynamically served content.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [count()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_count.asp) Method for the string
And with your code, it will look like this:

```
count = url.count(the_word)
print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} of word: {}'.format(url, count, the_word))
```